# Open source Rails apps that use fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm working on an existing app with a test suite based on vanilla Rails fixtures and `MiniTest`. Switching to `FactoryGirl` or the like is not an option.

I'd like to find a relatively complex open source Rails app to learn more about best practices with using fixtures. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant, it also uses some fixtures

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav. I can't get away from Shopify which is just around the corner :)

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) for myself, what is important:

- It creates unique data every time while seeding database.
  In some cases it does matter and better than same data. So, it is suitable for fixtures only;-)
- It has handy templates for most cases e.g. [phone](https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakerphonenumber).

You can check example in GitLab [repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/db/fixtures/development/05_users.rb).